# Replacing Inf by NaN results in AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a strange problem in Pandas. I want to replace any entry that has `np.Inf` with the value `np.NaN`. However, when I do:

```
df[df == np.Inf] = np.NaN
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'view'
```

The statement that produces the error specifically is:

```
df == np.Inf
```

I wonder if the problem is that I am running the above on a Dataframe with mixed types (see `dtypes` below). But if that is the case, how can I do this replacement still automatically?

```
In: df.dtypes
Out:
Year                            int64
Week                            int64
item_name                      object
item_uid                       object
Algorithm                      object
item Start                    float64
item 1/4                      float64
item 1/2                      float64
item 3/4                      float64
item Complete                 float64
Daily Nr Impressions          float64
date                   datetime64[ns]
Weekly rate                   float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Your code should've worked can you post some data to reproduce the error

Comment: I actually just tested your original code and it worked fine (Python 2.7 pandas 0.13.1)...

Comment: @Ffisegydd and Edchum. df.replace actually worked but not the code I included in the OP. I will try to include data in the OP.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`df.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to replace your `np.inf` values.

```
In [9]: import pandas as pd

In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, np.inf])

In [11]: df.replace(np.inf, np.nan)
Out[11]:
    0
0   1
1   2
2 NaN

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: FYI: ``df[~np.isfinite(df)] = np.nan`` is the correct indexing idiom

Comment: Also, ``df[df==np.inf] = np.nan`` DOES work in master/0.14, but not in 0.13.1, hmm. I do recall fixing this somewhere.

Comment: Don't forget about -np.inf! So, better do: df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)

Comment: or use Jeff's first example. That would find you `-np.inf`